# Scrape urls from multiple pages

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would to scrape urls from multiple pages from this starter link: https://www.transfermarkt.com/detailsuche/spielerdetail/suche/27403221/page/1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def extract(page):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://www.transfermarkt.com/detailsuche/spielerdetail/suche/27403221/page/1'
    r = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def trasform(soup):
    links = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'items')
    for item in links.find(class_='spielprofil_tooltip'):
        url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com' + item.attrs['href']
        
        urls = {
            'url': url
        }
        urllist.append(urls)
    return


urllist = []

for i in range(1,10,1):
    print(f'Getting page, {i}')
    c = extract(1)
    trasform(c)

df = pd.DataFrame(urllist)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('urlslist.csv', index=False)`
```

But I got this

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

in line 14, instead of find
`for item in links.find(class_='spielprofil_tooltip'):`

write find_all,
`for item in links.find_all(class_='spielprofil_tooltip'):`

This should fix the error.